# MySql Select count until find certain value

Tags: mysql, count

```
id  number my_id
 1    1     789  
 1    2     645
 1    3     222
 1    4     544
 1    5     155
```

With simple count result will equal 5

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS count FROM table WHERE id = 1
```

How I can count until find a certain value?

For example: count until my_id is '222' with count result = 3

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the order, what do you mean by "until my_id is 222"?

You can make a query like this(or the opposite) but this will use the `my_id` field to determine who should be counted:

```
SELECT count(id) as count
FROM YourTable
WHERE id = 1 AND my_id <= 222
```

**EDIT:** Your question missing some crucial information, but maybe you meant this:

```
SELECT COUNT(t.id) as count
FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.id = 1
  AND t.number <= (SELECT number FROM YourTable s
                   WHERE s.id = 1 and S.my_id = 222)
```

This query is relying on the fact the only 1 record will match the inner query .

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4dcdc0/1)

Comment: Doesn't works because query should be based on 'number' field

Comment: Then state that in the question!

Comment: Where did you stated that? and what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry now try to modify question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming number is sorted

```
select count(*) from t where `number`<=(select `number` from t where my_id=222)
```

Comment: Not only that it's a copy of my answer, its missing the OP filters and won't work as he expects.